# Usage of "I don't have" and "I have no"

Tags: negation

Which one is correct ?

> I don't have any occasion to take leave.
>
> I have no occasion to take leave.

Comment: I'd go for "There is no occasion for me to take leave" as occasions are not your possession.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amber's made a nice point. The 'occasion' is the subject of the sentence. For your example, she and I would say,

> There is no occasion for me to take leave.
>
> There aren't any occasions for me to take leave.

Both of these are equally correct.

Sadly, this doesn't answer your *question*. If I tweak the words so the sentence is a bit clearer (say, swap 'occasion' for 'reason), you get this:

> I don't have any reason to take leave.
>
> I have no reason to take leave.

Apart from the minor difference in emphasis (the '*no*' in the second one clearly expresses the lack of a reason, while the tone is milder in the first) the two are synonymous in meaning.

Comment: I don't think 'reason' has the same sense here.  'Occasion' is being used here in the sense of 'a favorable or appropriate time or juncture; an opportunity' (freedictionary.com, Def 3).  'I haven't had the chance to take leave' might thus be a better way to paraphrase it.

Comment: Ah, I was only looking for a word that would allow me to explain the two constructs; maintaining meaning wasn't all that important :)